# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked before, but I've looked through the different versions of this question and am not seeing an answer for my particular issue.

My code:

```
var display = {

difference: function(a) {
    return Math.abs(state.price - state.greens[a].pricePer30);
},
// Some more methods here
```

When I run the code, I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pricePer30' of undefined
```

However, if I run

```
console.log(display.difference(0))
```

It returns the correct answer.

When I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954051/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-object) question:

I thought that perhaps the argument I was using was in fact being re-used somewhere else in the script, so I changed the argument to read:

```
var display = {

difference: function(num) {
    return Math.abs(state.price - state.greens[num].pricePer30);
},
// Some more methods
```

But I get the same error message.

What should I look for in my code to fix this?

Comment: see what `num` is itself. console.log(num) and you will see it is an invalid key

Comment: Clearly `greens[0]` exists, but `greens[a]` for at least some values of `a` does not.  Debug on that line and find the value of `a` being used.  Then examine what's in `greens`.  Somewhere your logic is expecting to reference an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: and make sure the `num` is within the `state.greens` array bounds

Comment: Why not run in debug and check the greens array and the passed index?

Comment: @AmmarCSE - I ran console.log for both of those and they both returned undefined, so it's not an issue of those being variables elsewhere that are overriding my function.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel, so show how you call it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is clearly that state.greens[a] is undefined for a specific index a. Add a check before to get rid of the immidiate problem, but I'm guessing you're gonna have to investigate why it's undefined for index a as well.

```
if(typeof state.greens[a] !== "undefined") {
    return Math.abs(state.price - state.greens[a].pricePer30);
} else {
    console.warn("Found undefined state for index: ", a);
}
```